# trunc in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to used TRUNC in SQL Oracle but doens't work . I make a mistake ?

select
TRUNC(cal.DAY_DATE  - BIRTHDATE)/ 365 AS EMP_AGE,

from dual

Comment: Please clarify a meaning of "doesn't work": post an error message if any, current output and desired output with a description of what you expected to get in general words

Comment: @astentx, the truncate doesnt' work ... I have number with decimal

Comment: You need to add another ()... `TRUNC((cal.DAY_DATE - BIRTHDATE)/ 365) as emp_age` because you are currently TRUNC'ing the subtraction before the division.

Comment: It works as it should, because date difference is a number of days between two dates. What output do you want to get for date difference? Looks like this is a number of years between two dates. Then use `months_between(cal.DAY_DATE, BIRTHDATE)/12`, possibly with `trunc` around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the number of days between two dates and then divide by 365 and then round down, you can use:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(
         (SYSDATE - BIRTHDATE)
         / 365
       ) AS EMP_AGE
FROM   employees;
```

There are not always 365 days in a year so your calculation is going to be slightly wrong.

It is going to be more accurate to count the number of months using:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, birthdate)
         / 12
       ) AS emp_age
FROM   employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example below to accomplish what you are wanting to do. Just replace YOUR_TABLE with the table you want, and replace YOUR_BIRTHDAY_COLUMN with the name of the column that contains the birth date in the table you are querying from.

```
select FLOOR((trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(YOUR_BIRTHDAY_COLUMN)))/365) as AGE from YOUR_TABLE;
```